# Объясните пожалуйста новичку, почему цикл срабатывает один раз

Tags: javascript

Суть задачи заключается в том, что бы в `input` вводить определенный ключ из массива, после чего удаляются  значение в данном массиве, когда вводишь первый раз ключ, то значение удаляется, а вот во второй раз почему-то этого уже не происходит, во второй раз срабатывает почему-то данная часть кода:

`if(map === -1){out = 'Such value is not available!';}` - плиз, если кто шарит норм в программирование объясните новичку))

```js
let inp = null;
inp = document.querySelector('.inp');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
let valInp = ' ';
let arr = {
  1: 'sahsa',
  2: 'pasha',
  3: 'sahsa',
  4: 'vany',
  5: 'semeon',
  6: 'sahsa',
  7: 'alex',
  8: 'vany',
  9: 'pasha',
  10: 'masha'
}
inp.addEventListener('change', () => {
  valInp = inp.value;
})
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let out = ' ';
  let map = -1;
  for (let key in arr) {
    if (key === valInp) {
      map = 1;
      if (map === 1) {
        delete arr[key];
      }
    }
  }
  if (map === -1) {
    out = 'Such value is not available!';
  }
  for (let key in arr) {
    out += `${key} : ${arr[key]} <br>`;
    //out += arr[key] + "<br>";
  }
  console.log(arr);
  document.querySelector('.res').innerHTML += out + "<br>";
  inp.value = " ";
  valInp = " ";
})
```

Comment: `let key in arr` здесь key используется, как элемент массива, а здесь `delete arr[key];` как индекс. Это правильно?

Comment: эуэуууу, я думал ключик к свойству указывать нужно, что бы цикл понимал какой нужно элемент удалить, это же не splice где нужно по индексу удалять, или тут так и нужно ?

Comment: Вы же мутируете сам объект, по которому итерируете